# What does the option -C achieve in ls output?

Tags: command-line, ls, command, options

In the man pages it says:

```
-C     list entries by columns
```

However, I really cannot notice any difference between the output of `ls` or `ls -C`, could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Try piping `ls` to some command, like cat or tail.

Comment: @muru Show the difference but there is no difference when it prints directly to `stdout` so why such a functionality is needed?

Comment: maybe to save `ls`'s output to something but preserve how it actually appears. Or process it for some reasons but still show a nice form to the user.. Who knows? It's specified by POSIX, so if anyone has access to their discussions, we might know.

Comment: That's because `-C` is the default in this scenario. The option is turned on, whether you specify it or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add what @muru said in the comments; have a look at [`info coreutils ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting)

```
`-C'
`--format=vertical'
     List files in columns, sorted vertically.  This is the default for
     `ls' if standard output is a terminal.  It is always the default
     for the `dir' program.  GNU `ls' uses variable width columns to
     display as many files as possible in the fewest lines.
```

I take this to mean `-C` exists specifically for the case where you redirect or pipe the output and want to preserve columnation. Otherwise ls will switch to `ls -1` when it detects that it's not displaying to a terminal.